# ... のここが ... (adverb nominalization?)

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-の

I've been studying Japanese for years, but I still run into *everyday* language constructs that knock the wind out of me, and make me wonder if I slept through an entire week of Japanese class...

I stress that I am not talking about archaic Japanese, or technical writing, etc.  I'm talking about everyday stuff.

Here's the latest:

> 日本のここが辛い。

I understand this means something like this (*but please do correct me if I'm wrong!*):

> This is what is harsh about Japan.

What sends me for a loop is the "のここ" bit, because I expect the の particle to be followed by a noun, whereas I have always known ここ as something closer to an adverb.

OK, I know that in English (for example) one sometimes comes across the expression "the here and now", which renders "here" into a noun.  Maybe something like this is going on with "のここ"?

My question is: does this contstruction generalize?  Can one use phrases like "のそこ" or "のあそこ" or "の今" or "の明日", etc?

Can someone point to me to a detailed discussion of the linguistics/grammar that would encompass the language pattern exemplified by the quotation above?

---

**EDIT:** After I posted my question, I found the following example online:

> ここの冬はひどく寒いです。

While I can't say that this use of ここの strikes me as terribly familiar, I do find it quite intelligible.  It does not have the same disconcerting effect for me that "日本のここが辛い" has.  Arguably, this second sentence also nominalizes ここ, but note the difference in ordering: "ここの" vs. "のここ".

I can't quite explain why I find the first ("のここ") nominalization so much more bewildering than the second one ("ここの").

I suspect, however, that perhaps the *translation* into English that I gave to the first sentence is contributing to my disorientation.  A literal translation like "Japan's 'here' is harsh" would sound a bit odd *semantically* (something I am by now quite used to when I read Japanese), but not all that odd *syntactically.*  (BTW, if that literal translation were indeed correct, I would interpret it to mean something like "Being in Japan is harsh" or "Present reality in Japan is harsh".)

My point is this: the proper translation of my original example is a key aspect of this question.  If my translation is wrong, it could be that the correct translation, *by itself*, may suffice to dispel my confusion.

Therefore, I decided to add <kbd>translation</kbd> to this question's tags, even though translation was not my original motivation for posting it.

Comment: It may be simplest to think of ここ as "this place/part" (noun). 日本のここ = "this part of Japan", ここの冬 = "winter of this place".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your confusion probably stems from that ここ is usually translated *here* but is actually [a pronoun](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%93%E3%81%93/#jn-77801) as a Japanese word. In fact, ここ usually appears with particles and behaves like a noun.

On the other hand, 今日 or 明日 looks more like a normal noun, but it is often used adverbially as in 今日学校に行った. This is usually called 名詞の副詞的用法, which can be seen in English as in *I have lots of things to do **this month***.

So from the Japanese perspective, it is more 'adverb-ization of nouns'. Expressions like '..の今/明日/ここ' are all grammatical. Regarding Xのここ/そこ, these mean literally *this/that point of X*.

---

I guess the English *today* is originally an adverb which is turned into a noun, so an instance of 'adverb nominalization' in some sense.

Comment: I had suspected that translation may be the key to this question, but I did not expect it would be in such a straightforward way!  Thank you!  (BTW, I wish I could up-vote your avatar.  It's from my all-time favorite Japanese print.)